# Create Dialog Box with push buttons created dynamically

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, dialog, win32gui

I would like to create a Win32-based modal DialogBox, where the actual labels of the buttons are received as input at creation time. For example, clicking one button may cause two other buttons to appear. Since the button properties aren't known at compile time, I assume using a resource file isn't the solution. I also don't want to hide/disable buttons but just generate them dynamically.

The number of the buttons can be variable, but the order has to be maintained. For example, the order of buttons could be any of the following:

`A, B, C, D, E`

`B, C, E`

`C`

`A, B, E`

I do not want to have the following

`[A] B [C] D [E]` where `[X]` denotes a grayed out button

`[ ] B [ ] D [ ]` where `[ ]` denotes empty space

I have done some online search, where using `CreateWindow()` or `CreateWindowEx()` seems to be a/one way to use, but I could not find a simple working sample.

Does Microsoft have any such sample code anywhere?

Comment: *"I also don't want to hide/disable buttons but just generate them dynamically."* - Why that? What problem are you trying to prevent by creating/destroying instead of showing/hiding controls?

Comment: I don't want to show greyed out disabled buttons, I want to show
B C D
instead of:
[A] B C D [E], where [X] denotes a grayed out button

Comment: A hidden button doesn't display at all.

Comment: But would hidden buttons display something like [ ] B C D [ ]? Where [ ] denotes empty space,

Comment: Hidden controls do not take up space.

Comment: If every control has (x,y,width,height) values, wouldn't a hidden control just leave empty space in that located, unless all other controls are somehow moved?

Comment: The system doesn't provide a mechanism to adjust dialog controls automatically, so a dialog usually already implements that logic already.

Comment: Will you point to me an example please?

Comment: "*If every control has (x,y,width,height) values, wouldn't a hidden control just leave empty space in that located*" - yes. "*unless all other controls are somehow moved?*" - what is stopping you from moving them yourself? You are creating the controls, move them wherever you want, such as with `SetWindowsPos()`. Keep track of the HWNDs you create and which ones you want displayed at any given time. Then you can loop through that list, hiding the ones you don't want displayed, and moving around the ones you do want displayed.

Comment: I didn't know that moving buttons/controls is possible/feasible in this scenario. If so, I should be all set.

Comment: One question, do you need to destroy the button? For example, if you have enough buttons, you need to destroy one of them and reorder the remaining buttons to avoid empty space?

Comment: Another idea, you create a structure, one of the parameters is an array containing enough coordinates, and the other is the state of each coordinate. Whenever a button is created, the coordinates are extracted from the array and the coordinates are set as used. If the button is destroyed, the coordinates are set to unused. The remaining buttons are reordered according to this coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Given your description (just needing to change some button labels), I'd start with a resource file.

After you create the dialog, you can use [`GetDialogItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdlgitem) to retrieve a handle to the window for the button whose label you need to change. You can then use [`SetWindowText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowtexta) to set that control's label.

Likewise with clicking one button making two other buttons appear. In this case, the two buttons that aren't initially visible you'd mark as not visible in the resource file. Then when the user clicks the first button, you set the other two buttons to visible.

As a side note: in most cases, it would be better to just disable the other two buttons rather than actually hide them. Windows will draw them grayed out, so the user will recognize that clicking them won't have any effect (yet), but it still makes it clear that some other action will enable them.

At least in my experience, it's usually (quite a bit) easier to start with a resource file, and manipulate controls as needed rather than trying to create a complete dialog on your own from the ground up--and none of what you've mentioned in the question approaches the sort of thing that I'd see as justifying creating a dialog entirely on your own.

Just for completeness though, if you decide you really need to do that, you might want to take a look at [`CreateDialogIndirect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createdialogindirecta). This lets you build a data structure defining the dialog and the controls it contains, then create a dialog implementing them.

Comment: I thought about this initially, but how would I handle the variable number of buttons. I just updated my question with some examples above.

Comment: I was editing about the same time as you were, adding a reference to `CreateDialogIndirect`. It can/does work, but at least in my experience, using it is pretty painful. Using `CreateWindow` to create the container and all the controls on your own is worse--it's easy to create things, but handling tabbing between controls is decidedly non-trivial. Any of these can be done, but for what you've described, I'm 99% certain it'll be easier to use a resource file, and hide/show/move buttons as needed.

Comment: I looked at CreateDialogIndirect and after some difficulties I was able to programmatically generate a template (ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/using-dialog-boxes#creating-a-template-in-memory) , but it seems that once the DialogBox is created with this template in memory, it can't be changed. Or can it be changed?

Comment: @cpp19: Once it's created, it's just like a normal dialog. To make changes, you modify the data you fed to `CreateDialogIndirect` and create a new dialog with the modifications.

Comment: best you can do is to use mfc. you can check out petzold on winapi but doubt it does worth it to do

Comment: next thing you'll need is automation most probably and winapi doesn't have it (at least on that level where you're able to use it )

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин, by petzold do you mean this? http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/

Comment: @cpp19 yeah . 4th is better